# Ternary Operator / Replacing if/else with ternary operator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to replace an if else statement with a ternary operator

if the cost of vodka $24 return at discount price 18 (24 *.75)

This if else loop works fine and gives me the desired result but when i
try to convert it to ternary I get "expected ':'" error in xcode. What am I
doing wrong here?

ternary operator works like this
(condition) ? (executeFirst) : (executeSecond)

here is what I have:

---

```
NSUInteger cost = 24;
if (cost == 24) {
    return cost *= .75);
} else {
    return nil;
}
```

---

```
NSUInteger cost = 24;
(cost = 24) ? return cost *= .75 : return nil;

return cost;
```

}

Comment: Do not return `nil` for an NSInteger. Return `0` or some other desired value. `nil` is for object pointers, not primitives.

Comment: Why cost *= 0.75? And not cost * 0.75?

Answer (score 2):

Ternary operator is used to assign a value to some variable.

Use

```
cost = (cost == 24) ? cost * 0.75 : cost;
```

or:

```
return (cost == 24) ? cost*0.75 : cost;
```

Note the difference between '==' and '='. You must have made a typo or forgot about it in your code. '==' sign checks if left and right values are equal, and '=' assigns the right value to the left side (a variable).

Comment: @JoshCaswell Right. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign ternary operator value to some variable, o return it.

```
NSUInteger cost = 24;
cost = (cost == 24) ? cost * .75 : nil;
return cost;
```

Or

```
NSUInteger cost = 24;
return (cost == 24) ? cost * .75 : nil;
```

Comment: This one makes sense! but xcode is giving me this "Incompatiable pointer to integer conversion returning 'void *' from a function with result type 'NSUinteger' (aka 'unsigned long')" and "Pointer/integer type mismatch in conditional expression ('NSUinteger' (aka 'unsigned long') and 'void *')"

Comment: ahh, sorry You cant use `*=` in ternary operator

Comment: The use of `nil` is incorrect here, and is leading to that error, @Kero.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something like:

```
NSUInteger cost = 24;
return (cost == 24) ? cost *= .75 : return nil;
```

2 things:

1. The first part of the ternary operator (the condition) should be a boolean, you previously had an assignment (`==` vs. `=`)
2. Return the result of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator has to evaluate to something (think of it as a mini function that HAS TO return a value). For the ternary `condition ? one : two`, you can't have statements (e.g. `x = 3`) at `one` and `two`; they must be expressions. So in your case it would be

```
return (cost == 24 ? 0.75 * cost : nil);
```

Comment: Good explanation, but you can't use `nil` if `cost` is an `NSUInteger`. The else value should probably just be `cost`.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Agreed, I was mostly going for emphasis on the expressions part, so I just used the values he had in his code.